# Why are there so many files in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

Tags: hard-drive, cryptography

I am running out of disk space on C:-drive. We see many (millions of) files in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`

What are these files ?

Why are so many files created? How can we prevent this from happening?
Can these files be deleted?

Comment: Do you use Comodo firewall?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you have so many. I have 7 files in that location. I don't know what the files are though, so I can't give an answer, just thought I'd let you know so many files may not be normal.

Comment: How large are they? Are they even relevant to your space issue? If not, leave them be.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the answer by some analysis and testing. The problem is **caused by SSL checking performed by ESET antivirus software**.

**Disable SSL scanning in ESET** and these files will stop appearing in great quantities.

ESET SSL scanning is also connected to [MITM attack warning in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/720235/https-doesnt-work-with-chrome) (also see links posted in given Q/A and comments).

Comment: ESET does a MITM to decrypt SSL traffic so it can scan the contents. It therefore must generate a fake key for each SSL website you visit so your browser doesn't complain the connection has been compromised. Almost year old question brings into mind the current Lenovo-Superfish-Kommodia debacle where the private key to generate all those faked keys is easy to crack and the error checking is so ludicrous that its key regen will force a self-signed cert to be fully trusted if the cert is generated just right.

Comment: @FiascoLabs – yes I fully agree. This ESET case popped up on my mind when reading about Lenovo-Superfish-Kommodia.

Comment: More recognition of an ESET-related cause: https://forum.eset.com/topic/9782-increase-in-files-on-era-host-cprogramdatamicrosoftcrypto/

Answer (score 3):

The files are related to SSL certificates issued through the Windows webserver, IIS.

A solution to delete these files is suggested [here](http://www.systemcentercentral.com/Default.aspx?tabid=60&indexid=76874):

> OK so I have found a way to clear down the folder: forfiles /d -90 /C
>   "cmd /c del @file /F /A:AS"
>
> This looks for files older than 90 days and runs cmd - the del command
>   with force option and files with attributes A and S (archive &
>   system). I dont know why it wasn't working without the /A:AS on the
>   end, maybe because they are system files.

Forfiles is a utility to perform batch operations on multiple files.

**CAUTION:** before you proceed to remove the files, make sure they are not crucial to any production-critical web sites !

Comment: Also it's always good to have a fresh full backup before mucking about by deleting stuff you might not know the full extend of.  my 2c.

Comment: if I understand `forfiles` correctly, your command should contain `del @file` instead of `del *`. With `del *` you do not need `forfiles`, because `del *` simply deletes everything...

Comment: still no answer WHY those files are appearing and how it can be stopped...  I have millions, too and I would like to stop their creation. Unaffected systems have up to 100 files there.

Comment: LInk now returns 404 but a similar command can be found here: https://notes.ponderworthy.com/files-piling-up-in-c-programdata-microsoft-crypto-rsa-s-1-5-18 - contains breakdown of the command too.  Obviously use this only if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

There are four common reasons why the files in the MachineKeys folder are not automatically removed:

- There is a permission issue that is preventing OS to remove file from that folder. Compare the folder permissions with the ones listed in [this document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/278381/default-permissions-for-the-machinekeys-folders#:%7E:text=Summary,Internet%20Explorer%20use%20this%20folder.)
- There is a code related issue. The application is not removing X.509 certificates once it uses them for communication. [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527477/clean-my-machinekeys-folder-by-removing-multiple-rsa-files-without-touching-iis)
- A security software might be performing SSL check and causing these files to persist. Try disabling this software
- Enterprise CA might be failing to respond the request. Check Event Viewer logs for the failed requests

Source: [Remove older files in MachineKeys folder](https://port135.com/2020/08/12/remove-older-files-machinekeys/)