# HTTPS doesn't work with Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet, https, eset

I have problem similar to this: [HTTPS connections fail with Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/559276/https-connections-fail-with-chrome).

For a long time my Google Chrome browser worked perfectly, but yesterday something happened, and I can't open any of https sites. I get error 101: ERROR_CONNECTION_RESET. I tried to reinstall chrome, but it gave no result. I reinstalled it once again, but differently (I downloaded installer and performed installation offline). It worked, but after computer reboot, the problem came back.

I'm using Eset antivirus, but I don't think it's the problem. I disabled it and I disabled its firewall, and nothing changed.

Futhermore, I've got a problem with lots of files in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\ directory. I don't know. Maybe this issues are related.

Could someone help?

I forgot to add:
I tried to restore my system to time when Chrome worked. It gave no effect. 
Internet Explorer works.

Comment: Actually, you have a problem similar to http://superuser.com/questions/720395/, right down to the use of ESET and the timing.

Comment: You were right. Switching off SSL scan in ESET solved the problem. Thanks.